# Turn out "good" vs turn out "well"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Should one say:

> "turn out good" or "turn out well"

I have always preferred the latter, but found the form "turn out good" in the book by Raymond Murphy: "English Grammar in use".

Comment: It would depend upon the context - which you haven't given us.

Comment: Can you at least show us the full sentence you found in the book?

Answer (score 7):

"Turn out good" is fine when *good* is actually an adjective.

> With his upbringing he'll probably become a violent criminal, but he might turn out good.

Comment: Unless, of course we are referring to his wardrobe, In which case he might *turn out well*.

Comment: To me, the implied linking verb must be made explicit for "good" to work out:

"...but he might turn out _to_ _be_ good."

Otherwise, it appears "good" is erroneously being used as an adverb modifying the phrasal verb "turn out".

Comment: @Monty Perhaps the parallelism would be clearer with "he'll probably become violently criminal, but he might turn out good," as that has two contrasted adjectives.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That helps, but "become" is clearly understood to be a linking verb (the "be-" prefix might subconsciously underscore it to be a being rather than doing verb) while "turn out" isn't.

Comment: Sorry, *become* is a not a "linking verb" (copula); it's a verb indicating transition, much like *turn out.*

Comment: "Becoming" is about the transition between two states of being.

`George W. Bush was President at 11:59:59 am, January 20, 2009.
 Barack H. Obama Jr. became President a second later.`

It's difficult to explain how "President" is the predicate nominative in the first sentence but the object in the second.  "Become" does indicate a transition between two states of being, but the being is more important than the transition.

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/linking-verbs.html and http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/linkingverb.htm agree with me that "become" is a linking verb.

Comment: Continuing on the Presidential theme, here's "become" taking both a predicate nominative AND an adverb:

`Grover Cleveland is the only person to become President twice (non-consecutively).`

Comment: @Monty Harder: There are lots of verbs in English, like *turn out*, that can take adjectives in the predicate position, but which are not usually on the lists of linking verbs given in ESL classes. For instance, would you say *"I painted my house blue"* or *"I painted my house bluely"*?

Comment: @PeterShor That would depend on the mood I was in when painting.

In your example, "blue" clearly modifies "house" rather than "painted", describing the resulting state rather than the process.  It also seems to me that any adverbs modifying "painted" would naturally fall either just before or just after the verb, not after the object.  (I evenually painted my house white.)

The question "how did it turn out?" (in which "how" is an adverb modifying the phrasal verb "turn out") is quite common.  I'm struggling to think of a similar question that uses a form indicating an adjective instead.

Answer (score 4):

Would you say

> that cake turned out delicious

or

> that cake turned out deliciously?

In the first case, it's a predicate adjective describing the cake. In the second, it's an adverb describing the process of turning out. The adjective makes more sense in this case, and more people use it. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turned+out+delicious%2Cturned+out+deliciously&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cturned%20out%20delicious%3B%2Cc0).

For the question of *turned out good/well*, which one is correct depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, for many decades it was stressed in school that **well** should be used with verbs and **good** with nouns.

> This cake turned out well. It's good.
>
> It was quite a mess at first, but in the end it turned out well for
>   everyone.
>   --That's good.

The schools wouldn't have stressed this usage "rule" if many native speakers weren't violating it all the time.

Many of the people who violate this rule today have had little schooling, and so the idea has arisen that to "misuse" **good** and **well** is a sign the person is poorly educated or otherwise resistant to education. We have  the stereotype of the beer-guzzling couch-potato watching mindless action movies in which things routinely explode:

**"That blew up real good!"**

So, many native speakers will think you're an uneducated bumpkin if you say "That worked out real good". Telling them that you're a descriptivist not a prescriptivist won't get you very far. They are not likely to know what those words mean.

Answer (score 1):

I don't care how relaxed people get about things like this. I still like the idea of distinguishing between an adjective and an adverb.

To me, "That turned out real good" means (e.g.) "That turned out not to be evil."

"That turned out real well" means it turned out the way it was hoped or expected to.